# Как получить список информации запущенных процессов на python

Tags: python, windows, list

и так, я знаю что

```py
print('\n'.join([p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()])
```

выведет список всех процессов в системе в столбик, но выведит он только название, а как сделать так, чтобы вместе с названием, он выводил PID процесса, оперативную память (которую он занимает) и т.д, примерно также как и команда tasklist в cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться модулем `subprocess`. Он дает разработчику возможность запускать процессы программ из Python:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

for i in Popen('tasklist', stdout=PIPE).stdout.readlines():
    print(i.decode('cp866', 'ignore'))
```

Comment: как исправить кодировку? мне нужно это записать в файл, но когда я это делаю то у меня слетает кодировка, вот скрин https://imgur.com/a/CV0XzcL

Comment: @Ves3anGo Попробуйте декодировать в 'utf-8'(`decode('utf-8')`)

Comment: как, https://pastebin.com/PGUMR3fd? @Tehnorobot

Comment: @Ves3anGo попробуйте написать так: with open(ZipPATH['Other'] + "\\processlist.txt", 'w', encoding='uft-8') as getprocessL:

Comment: не работает, пробовал

Comment: @Ves3anGo Попробуйте так: `getprocessL.write(i.decode('cp1251', 'ignore'))`